# Find JRE version of running application on Linux server

Tags: java, linux

I am getting the results below, do they mean I have JDK 1.7.0_45 and the JRE is 1.42?

```
$ javac -version
Eclipse Java Compiler v_677_R32x, 3.2.1 release, Copyright IBM Corp 2000, 2006. All rights reserved.
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
$ alternatives --config java
There is 1 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           **/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.4.2-gcj/bin/java**

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:
```

Comment: No, there is no such thing as "JRE 1.42". The output means you're using Java 7 update 45. Java is installed in such a way that it overrides what the alternatives mechanism provides, so the output of the `alternatives` command is not important. You also have the Eclipse Java compiler in your path instead of the Java compiler from the JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually I am getting "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" error after uploading a external jar file to Informatica powercenter Java transformation. The class files in jar file have been compiled with 1.7 and tried with other versions too after getting this error while running session. I suspect my Informatica application is running in JRE 1.4 ? does it make sense or any other thoughts ?

Comment: That error means you have classes compiled with JDK 7 but you are running them on an older Java version, so somehow indeed something older than the Java 7 that you have installed is being picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that you have two versions of Java installed:

- The Java on your PATH is Java 1.7.0.  I think it is an Oracle build rather than a build from your Linux system's package repository.
- The Java configured using `alternatives` looks like a GCJ Java that is compatible with Java 1.4.2.  It was probably installed from your package repository. IMO, it is inadvisable to use this from a technical standpoint.  In fact, I would recommend uninstalling it.

---

> Actually I am getting "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" error after uploading a external jar file to Informatica powercenter Java transformation.

That implies that Informatica is using the Java 1.4.2 installation.

---

Now, the version of Java that an application uses will depend on what version of Java the application's launcher / launch script is using.  That could depend on a number of things:

- If the launcher uses an absolute path for the `java` command, then that is what will use.
- If the launcher uses a simple name (e.g. `java`) then the version used will depend on the launcher's `$PATH`.  This is probably what is happening ... and the `$PATH` used is different from your shell's `$PATH`.

---

So what is the solution?

- You could add the Oracle Java install to the `alternatives` system.  See `man alternatives` or Google for instructions using "java oracle alternatives install"
- You could tweak the $PATH used by the application's launcher.
- Depending on your Linux distro, you could install an OpenJDK 1.7.0 JDK or JRE from the package repos.  That will (should) add the new installed Java to the `alternatives` database, so that you can select it instead of the old GCJ 1.4.2 installation.

Answer (score 0):

In general, here's how you can find out which JRE a program uses:

### When you're at liberty to start the program

Use [strace](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to start the program: `strace yourJavaProgram`.

This should reveal the file path of the JRE that `yourJavaProgram` uses:

```
readlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/exe", "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin"..., 4096) = 37
```

### When you want to get the used Java version of a *running* program

- Find the ID of the relevant `java` process with `pgrep --list-full java`. Let's say the process ID is 1234.
- Find open files: `ls -l /proc/1234/fd`. This might produce something like:

  `lr-x------ 1 mb mb 64 Oct 19 10:52 3 -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/lib/modules`
- To see the memory map, including loaded files, of your process: `pmap --show-path 1234`. Excerpt of example output:

  `000055d31b9a7000      4K r---- /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin/java`